# Changing Javascript animation

Tags: javascript, animation, navbar

I'm using this code to make my navbar change to a fixed navbar when the user scrolls down a bit. How can I make the animation slide up instead of slide down? The original fiddle can be found here http://jsfiddle.net/CZ87p/132/.

```
var nav = $('.nav');
var scrolled = false;

$(window).scroll(function () {

    if (20 < $(window).scrollTop() && !scrolled) {
        nav.addClass('visible').animate({ top: '0px' });
        scrolled = true;
    }

   if (20 > $(window).scrollTop() && scrolled) {
        nav.removeClass('visible').animate('top', '-30px');
        scrolled = false;      
    }
});
```

Comment: You mean slide up instead of simple hide ? When the scroll bar reach top.

Answer (score 1):

You could animate both `height` and the `top` in order to keep a fixed baseline:

```
if (20 < $(window).scrollTop() && !scrolled) {
    nav.addClass('visible').animate({ height: '20px', top: '10px' });
    scrolled = true;
}

if (20 > $(window).scrollTop() && scrolled) {
    nav.removeClass('visible').css({'height': 0, top: '30px' });
    scrolled = false;      
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/762z9/15/)

Comment: Awesome that's what I need except the navbar should be at the very top not 20px down. I tried changing the 20px to 0 and it messed it up.

Comment: You'll need to modify the top animates by 10.

...    top: '0px'

...    top: '20px'

Here is a working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/762z9/13/) based on the original answer.

Answer (score 1):

In case that this is what are you looking, maybe you have explained wrong what you need.

```
var nav = $('.nav');
var scrolled = false;

$(window).scroll(function () {

    if (20 < $(window).scrollTop() && !scrolled) {
        nav.animate({ top : '0px' });
        scrolled = true;
    }

   if (20 > $(window).scrollTop() && scrolled) {
       nav.animate({ top : '-30px' });
       scrolled = false;      
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CZ87p/142/